# Auto increment the id when date is changed

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in mysql to auto increment an ID when the date is changed?

I have a table like this and the id must be auto increment when the day is changed.

| ID | Name | Date Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adi | 2022-06-29 17:00:00 |
| 1 | Adi | 2022-06-29 17:00:00 |
| 1 | Adi | 2022-06-29 17:00:00 |
| 2 | Adi | 2022-06-30 17:00:00 |
| 2 | Adi | 2022-06-30 17:00:00 |
| 3 | Adi | 2022-07-01 17:00:00 |
| 3 | Adi | 2022-07-01 17:00:00 |
| 4 | Adi | 2022-07-02 17:00:00 |
| 4 | Adi | 2022-07-02 17:00:00 |

Comment: Why not auto-generate the `id` column? `id AS datediff(date_time, curdate())`.

Comment: Im a bit confused. Why do some IDs exist multiple times?

Comment: Do not store, calculate in the query using DENSE_RANK().

Comment: @MF714 It seems that for some reason the OP wants to add redundancy to the table. And also, the column name `ID` is poorly chosen, since it implies uniqueness.

Comment: Adding a group-wise auto increment field to an innodb table is not straightforward. You can use triggers to accomplish the task, but you are better positioned to calculate it on the fly as @Akina has suggested.